# С помощью каких средств можно получить статистику о времени выполнения каждого метода?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Допустим, есть программа и мне нужно в конце ее работы получить некоторую статистику.

Что-то типа списка методов с кол-во времени, которое в них просидела программа.

Например, некоторый метод вызывался 10 раз из разных мест и выполнялся по 1 сек=> в статистике должно быть написано 10 сек выполнения.

С помощью каких средств я это могу сделать?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: http://itnote.ru/2010/09/28/nlog/

Comment: Такие инструменты называются профайлерами (Profiler) - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927/what-are-some-good-net-profilers

Answer (score 3):

Инструменты для сбора подобной статистики называются Профайлерами (Profiler).

*MSDN - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/profiling-tools-apis*
*Более предметный вопрос и ответы есть на enSO - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927/what-are-some-good-net-profilers*

Answer (score 2):

Инструмент "**Производительность и диагностика**" (Alt+F2). Выбрать "Выборка циклов ЦП"

Подробнее [здесь](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms182372.aspx)